# Object Body invalid

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have following error please help me out to solve this

```
SQL> alter package AML.DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT compile body;

Warning: Package Body altered with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for PACKAGE BODY AMLOCK_ALAMTHAL.DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
13/9     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
13/16    PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT_FFI.GETKEY' must
         be declared

19/9     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
19/16    PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT_FFI.GETKEY' must
         be declared

25/9     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
27/17    PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT_FFI.GETKEY' must
         be declared

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------

36/9     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
38/17    PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT_FFI.GETKEY' must
         be declared

60/9     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
60/16    PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT_FFI.GETKEY' must
         be declared

68/9     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
68/16    PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT_FFI.GETKEY' must

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
         be declared

76/9     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
78/15    PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT_FFI.GETKEY' must
         be declared

87/9     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
89/17    PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT_FFI.GETKEY' must
         be declared

99/9     PL/SQL: Statement ignored

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
99/27    PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT_FFI.DESENCRYPT'
         must be declared

106/9    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
106/16   PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT_FFI.DESENCRYPT'
         must be declared
```

Answer (score 1):

The package body won't compile because you don't have the correct dependencies in place. In this case DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT_FFI. Now you could try to put that in place as well, but let's ask the big question:

DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT is an Oracle supplied library and belongs to SYS user. Why are you trying to install it in your own schema?

You have tagged your question `[oracle12c]` and I guess that's why. This package is no longer available in 12c. DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT has been deprecated for a long time (for security reasons). You should be using [DBMS_CRYPTO](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_CRYPTO.html#GUID-1C98C203-29EF-488D-A5FA-42AD4BD7718D) instead.

This may mean you need to re-write your code to use the new package, but trying to retrofit a de-supported package is a big mistake.